How to use GtkGestureLongPress and GtkGestureClick in the same GtkWindow/GtkWidget?
I am trying do 3 different task by single press, double press and long press on the window/widget. To do this i am trying to use GtkGestureLongPress and GtkGestureClick. But the problem is that whenever i want to do a long press, the single press is running automatically. How this can be done? can anybody check it?
This is the demo script, thank you----
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

gboolean single = TRUE;
void click_event (GtkGesture *gesture,
                  int n_press,
                  gdouble x,
                  gdouble y,
                  gpointer user_data)

{
    if (n_press > 1) single = FALSE;
}

void stopp_event (GtkGesture *gesture, gpointer user_data)
{
    if (single == FALSE)
        g_print("Double click\n");
        //do task on double click
    else 
        g_print("Single click\n");
        //do task on single click
    single = TRUE;
}

void long_press (GtkGestureLongPress* self,
                 gdouble x,
                 gdouble y,
                 gpointer user_data)
{
     g_print ("LongPress %f %f\n", x, y);
     //do task on long press
}


static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));

  GtkGesture *gesture = gtk_gesture_click_new();
  gtk_gesture_single_set_button(GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE(gesture), 0);
  gtk_widget_add_controller(window,(GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER(gesture)));
  g_signal_connect (gesture, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (click_event), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (gesture, "stopped",G_CALLBACK(stopp_event),NULL);

  GtkGesture* gesture_long_press = gtk_gesture_long_press_new();
  gtk_gesture_single_set_button(GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE(gesture_long_press), GDK_BUTTON_PRIMARY);
  gtk_gesture_single_set_exclusive (GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE (gesture_long_press), TRUE);
  gtk_event_controller_set_propagation_phase((GtkEventController  *)gesture_long_press, GTK_PHASE_CAPTURE);
  gtk_gesture_long_press_set_delay_factor ((GtkGestureLongPress *)gesture_long_press, 1);
  gtk_widget_add_controller (window, GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture_long_press));
  g_signal_connect (gesture_long_press, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (long_press), window);

  gtk_window_present ((GtkWindow *)window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;
  #if GLIB_CHECK_VERSION(2, 74, 0)
      app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS); 
  #else
        app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE); 
  #endif
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}


The question is similar to the following: How to ignore double-clicks and detect single-clicks in C with GTK4 (< 4.10)? .
It is therefore important that the program waits for the timeout and only then decides how to evaluate the click.
How this can be programmed, I have shown here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/79159604/22768315.
Have fun programming.

Yes, i am testing on the script. Trying to add GtkGestureLongPress on it. But still not successful. Thank you :)

After some testing i found a solution, and it works. If anyone has any alternative and better method please let me know. Thank you :)
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

gboolean single = TRUE;
gboolean longPress = FALSE;

void press_event (GtkGesture *gesture,
                  int n_press,
                  gdouble x,
                  gdouble y,
                  gpointer user_data)

{
        longPress = TRUE;
}

void released_event (GtkGesture *gesture,
                     int n_press,
                     gdouble x,
                     gdouble y,
                     gpointer user_data)

{
    if (n_press > 1) single = FALSE;
        longPress = FALSE;
}

void stopp_event (GtkGesture *gesture, gpointer user_data)
{
     if (single == FALSE){
         g_print("Double click\n");
 
     }else {
          if (longPress == FALSE)
               g_print("Single click\n");
     }
     single = TRUE;
     longPress = TRUE;
}

void long_press (GtkGestureLongPress* self,
                 gdouble x,
                 gdouble y,
                 gpointer user_data)
{
     g_print("long pressed\n");
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));

  GtkGesture *gesture = gtk_gesture_click_new();
  gtk_gesture_single_set_button(GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE(gesture), GDK_BUTTON_PRIMARY);
  gtk_widget_add_controller(window,(GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER(gesture)));
  g_signal_connect (gesture, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (press_event), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (gesture, "released", G_CALLBACK (released_event), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (gesture, "stopped",G_CALLBACK(stopp_event), NULL);

  GtkGesture* gesture_long_press = gtk_gesture_long_press_new();
  gtk_gesture_single_set_button(GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE(gesture_long_press), GDK_BUTTON_PRIMARY);
  gtk_gesture_single_set_exclusive (GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE (gesture_long_press), TRUE);
  gtk_event_controller_set_propagation_phase((GtkEventController  *)gesture_long_press, GTK_PHASE_CAPTURE);
  gtk_gesture_long_press_set_delay_factor ((GtkGestureLongPress *)gesture_long_press, 1);
  gtk_widget_add_controller (window, GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture_long_press));
  g_signal_connect (gesture_long_press, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (long_press), NULL);

  gtk_window_present ((GtkWindow *)window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;
  #if GLIB_CHECK_VERSION(2, 74, 0)
      app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS); 
  #else
    app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE); 
  #endif
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}

